# How to save generated pdf in the web app directory [xdocreport]?

Tags: java, struts2, xdocreport

I am using **`xdocreport`** to generate a **`pdf`** document from **`*.docx`** files. I use **`struts2`** for implementation. I followed this https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingStruts2

I do have it working correctly, it does generate **`pdf`** and fills out the **`docx`** files with everything from the java.

My problem is: once the cycle is done, it throws the generated file directly to the user for download. So once the `xdocreport` generates everything, the user's browser will start downloading it.

Instead, I want the generated **`pdf`** be saved in the web app [*or in the same drive separate folder]* directory, and then from there I would like to ask the user if he wants to download it or no, if he clicks yes, then download it. Also, I have to have the backup of the generated **`pdf`** document, so I have to somehow first generate and save it in web app  [*or in the same drive separate folder]* folder and after that give it to the user.

How can I change it's behavior?

EDIT1 [based on below answer]:

So now it throws this exception, but even though it throws it I can see the converted pdf shown on the browser but I can't open the pdf document itself, which is generated in the filesystem.

```
* ERROR 2016-08-04 09:33:16,079 ExceptionConverter: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException (XWPF2PDFViaITextConverter.java [qtp559888791-19])
* ERROR 2016-08-04 09:33:16,096 Error while executing action (ExceptionInterceptor.java [qtp559888791-19])
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.XDocConverterException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: ExceptionConverter: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at     fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.poi.itext.XWPF2PDFViaITextConverter.convert(XWPF2PDFViaITextConverter.java:72)
at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.convert(AbstractXDocReport.java:713)
at org.apache.struts2.views.xdocreport.AbstractXDocReportResult.doProcessReportWithConverter(AbstractXDocReportResult.java:561)
at org.apache.struts2.views.xdocreport.AbstractXDocReportResult.doExecute(AbstractXDocReportResult.java:284)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:369)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:273)
```

Comment: Saving anything in the web app directory is a terrible idea. If you are running out of an unexpanded WAR file there is NO web app directory. If you must save to disk you must use the system property java.io.tmpdir, and ensure that it is set correctly in your deployment.

Comment: @JimGarrison, agree. I could create a separate folder in the same drive, but the question remains the same. How could one change the behaviour of `xdoxreport` to save the generated file in the server side first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the page you gave a link to, you can set param download to false and that will disable download.

```
<action name="DisplayProject" class="example.DisplayProject">
  <result name="success" type="xdocreport">
  <param name="location">/docx/DocxProjectWithVelocityList.docx</param>
  <param name="templateEngine">Velocity</param>
  <param name="fieldAsList">developers.Name,developers.LastName</param>
  <param name="download">false</param>
</result>
```

and to save file in web app folder, I guess you can

```
public void populateContext(IXDocReport report, IContext context)
        throws Exception {
context.put("project", getProject());
context.put("developers", getDevelopers());

try (FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "filename")) {
    report.process(context, fOut);
} catch (Exception e) {
     // Handle exception
}
```

}

Just assumptions, not tested.

Comment: Is this is a full exception? Does it still sends file to browser?

Comment: no, it doesn't send it to the browser as download. It just shows the file opened in the browser, and I also do have the generated pdf file and I can open it too. So, now it's working, but for some reason it throws this exception after the job gets done somewhere around 20-30 sec after

Comment: I think you have to handle FileOutputStream properly. See updated code